# Correct Async/Await usage with Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, async-await, axios

I'm working with axios to post user responses to a database. I'm using this set up shown below to handle many posts back to back. I'm wanting to make sure that this is the correct set up to avoid backing up requests.

**Is this the correct way to use async and await when using Axios?**

```
// Frontend React Code
// Posting conclusionInput to Mongodb
const postConclusion = async () => {
  await axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      conclusion: conclusionInput,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "http://localhost:4000/conclusion",
  }).then((res) => console.log(res));
};

//Backend Node / Express code
app.post("/conclusion", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Attempting to post the conclusion");
  User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, async (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (user) {
      (user.conclusion = req.body.conclusion), await user.save();
      res.send();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: In the first function you are mixing async with .then, In the second you are mixing async with callbacks. Both will work fine but not the best practice usually.

Comment: @ISAE Thanks! I understand the .then comment but can you explain the mixing async with callbacks comment?

Comment: Assuming (based on syntax) that you are using mongoDb/mongoose, the `findOne` method could be written in either callback or async/await style. `let user = await user.findOne({username: name})`

Comment: That will of course require you to add async keyword at the router fuction: `app.post("/conclusion", async (req, res) => {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Frontend

In an `async` function use `await` and `try/catch`. Any `.then` calls can be rolled out into `const x = await y` variables.

Return values from promise functions, in case you want to use them.

```
const postConclusion = async () => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      conclusion: conclusionInput,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "http://localhost:4000/conclusion",
  })
  console.log(res)
  return res
};
```

#### Backend

Again, if you are going with `async` use that API consistently.

Mongoose provides a [promise API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), so use that too.

```
app.post("/conclusion", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Attempting to post the conclusion");
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.user.username })
    if (!user) {
      return res.send('not found')
    }
    user.conclusion = req.body.conclusion
    await user.save()
    return res.send('saved')
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.send('error')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using async await, setting an await call to a variable is equal to the parameter in a .then callback

```
// Frontend React Code
// Posting conclusionInput to Mongodb
const postConclusion = async () => {
 // Set the await call to a variable. 
  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      conclusion: conclusionInput,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "http://localhost:4000/conclusion",
  })
 // Now no need for .then()!! This is why async/await is so nice. 
 console.log(res)
};

//Backend Node / Express code
app.post("/conclusion", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Attempting to post the conclusion");
  User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, async (err, user) => {
    // You need to send the error to the request. Otherwise, the 
    // request will keep waiting for a response until it times out.
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
    if (user) {
      // Side note: these should all be on separate lines:
      user.conclusion = req.body.conclusion
      await user.save();
      // You should also send a status code and a response message
      res.status(200).send({status: "Success}");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I also made some comments on some improvements to your backend code :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended have a folder called "services" and inside it has yours services by backend.

> services/
> getData.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getData = () => {
  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/conclusion");
};
```

> App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getData } from "./services/getData";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // save the value of service
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      getData().then((res) => {
        setData(res?.data);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, []); // execute once
  return <div className="App">{data}</div>;
}
```

Comment: How does separating folders answers the question regarding correct use of async / await?

Comment: The try/catch here would only catch synchronous errors. In a non `async` function use `.catch` or use an `async` function.

Comment: Also needs  a `return` in `getData`